# How to use middleware after resolver in graphene?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

Using Graphql in Node, you can use middlewares **BEFORE** or **AFTER** the resolver, using, for example, [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-middleware-zie3iphithxy).

In Python, using [Graphene](https://graphene-python.org/), I could only find a way to use middleware **BEFORE** the resolver.

Is there a way to use middlewares **AFTER** the resolver in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```py
class SomeMiddleware(object):
    def resolve(self, next, root, info, **args):
        next_node = next(root, info, **args)
        ...logic...
        return next_node
```

Comment: Thanks! And do you know if I can get the answer graphene returns? Or only the data fetched is available?

Comment: The answer, as in the value returned by the middleware's resolver?

Comment: No, the answer returned by the graphene. If I ask `{city {id}}` and the resolver returns `{city: {id: 1, name: 'ny'}}`, how can I get the response `{city: {id: 1}}` only? I'm trying to create a middleware to log requests/responses.

Comment: Oh! Does it? I was under the impression that graphene doesn't bother with resolving fields which have not been requested. The middleware fires after graphene is done with processing the request, so definitely this response gets forwarded to the client, but that's not how graphene works! Are you sure?

Comment: Yes. The resolver doesn't know what was asked. So it responds with the full data. Then, graphene maps the data and remove what was not asked. But I don't know how to get the final response, with the data already stripped out.

Comment: @frozenOne thanks for the answer, can you help a bit more, so i basically have a line of code i have to make sure , is executed only once during query lifetime, and that too at the end of query only.
but as i put my code after the next_node line, it is being run multiple times , any solution for that??

Comment: @iron_man83 hey sorry, i saw it late. but did you can add a middleware that only runs post the query has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django middlewares to format output graphql query or mutation

```py
class FormatOutputMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # Get the graphql response
        data = json.loads(response.content.decode("UTF-8"))

        # do something with data

        response.content = json.dumps(data).encode("UTF-8")
        return response
```